# in flink processFunction, all mapstate is empty in onTimer() function

Tags: apache-flink

I want implements the aggregationFunction by the processKeyedFunction, because the default aggregationFunction does not support rich function,
Besides, I tryed the aggreagationFunction + processWindowFunction(https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html), but it also cannot satisfy my needs, so I have to use the basic processKeyedFunction to implement the aggregationFunction, the detail of my problem is as followed:

in processFunction, , I define a windowState for stage the aggregation value of elements, the code is as followed:

```
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
followCacheMap = FollowSet.getInstance();
windowState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(windowStateDescriptor);
currentTimer = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<Long>(
        "timer",
        Long.class
));
```

in processElement() function, I use the windowState (which is a MapState initiate in open function) to aggregate the window element, and register the first timeServie to clear current window state, the code is as followed:

```
 @Override
public void processElement(FollowData value, Context ctx, Collector<FollowData> out) throws Exception 
{
      if ( (currentTimer==null || (currentTimer.value() ==null) || (long)currentTimer.value()==0 ) && value.getClickTime() != null) {
            currentTimer.update(value.getClickTime() + interval);
            ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer((long)currentTimer.value());
        } 
       windowState = doMyAggregation(value);
}
```

in onTimer() function, first, I register the next timeService in next One minute, and clear the window State

```
 @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<FollowData> out) throws Exception {
        currentTimer.update(timestamp + interval);   // interval is 1 minute
        ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer((long)currentTimer.value());
        
        out.collect(windowState);
        windowState.clear();
     }
```

but when the program is running , I found that all the windowState in onTimer is empty, but it is not empyt in processElement() function,  I don't know why this happens, maybe the execution logic is different, how can I fix this,
Thanks in advance !

---

---

### new added code about doMyAggregation() part

---

windowState is a MapState ,  key is "mykey", value is an self-defined Object AggregateFollow

```
public class AggregateFollow {
    private String clicked;
    private String unionid;
    private ArrayList allFollows;
    private int enterCnt;
    private Long clickTime;
```

}

and the doMyAggregation(value) function is pretty much like this , the function of doMyAggregation is to get all the value whose source field is 'follow', but if there are no values whose field is 'click' during  1 minute, the 'follow' value should be obsolete,   in a word , it's like a join operation of 'follow' data and 'click' data,

```
AggregateFollow acc = windowState.get(windowkey);
    String flag = acc.getClicked();
    ArrayList<FollowData> followDataList = acc.getAllFollows();
    if ("0".equals(flag)) {
        if ("follow".equals(value.getSource())) {
            followDataList.add(value);
            acc.setAllFollows(followDataList);
        }
        if ("click".equals(value.getSource())) {
            String unionid = value.getUnionid();
            clickTime = value.getClickTime();
            if (followDataList.size() > 0) {
                ArrayList listNew = new ArrayList();
                for (FollowData followData : followDataList) {
                    followData.setUnionid(unionid);
                    followData.setClickTime(clickTime);
                    followData.setSource("joined_flag");   // 
                }
                acc.setAllFollows(listNew);
            }
            acc.setClicked("1");
            acc.setUnionid(unionid);
            acc.setClickTime(clickTime);
            windowState.put(windowkey, acc);
        }
    } else if ("1".equals(flag)) {
        if ("follow".equals(value.getSource())) {
            value.setUnionid(acc.getUnionid());
            value.setClickTime(acc.getClickTime());
            value.setSource("joined_flag");  
            followDataList.add(value);
            acc.setAllFollows(followDataList);
            windowState.put(windowkey, acc);
        }
    }
```

because of performance problem,  original windowAPI is not a valid choice for me, the only way here I think is to use processFunction + ontimer and Guava Cache ,
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the type of windowState from MapState to ValueState, and the problem is solved, maybe it is a bug or something, can anyone can explain this?

Comment: I haven't understood what your code is doing, so it's hard to say for sure what the issue is/was. However, MapState is often misunderstood. MapState gives you a separate hashmap for every key of the stream(s) involved -- so you end up with a sharded map mapping from keys to maps. If you only need to map keys to values, then ValueState is more appropriate. But you shouldn't use ValueState where the values are maps, as MapState is optimized to handle that case more efficiently.

Comment: At first, I stores my aggregated values in mapState, but I didn't treate  it as a map, because the key is a  constant string, so it is actually a mapState with just one key,  so I feel confused because I think it should have worked like a valueState

Comment: You're right, a MapState with just the one key should work like a ValueState.

Answer (score 0):

If `windowState` is empty, it would be helpful to see what `doMyAggregation(value)` is doing.

It's difficult to debug this, or propose good alternatives, without more context, but `out.collect(windowState)` isn't going to work as intended. What you might want to do instead would be to iterate over this `MapState` and collect each key/value pair it contains to the output.

Comment: you're right, David,  I simplified the code at out.collect(windowState) , and I updated the code about  doMyAggregation()  operation part,

Comment: I wonder if it is because the order to access the windowState of processElement Context and onTimer Context, I am not familiar with the basic mechanism of flink,  much Appreciated !

Comment: How do you know that anything is actually being stored into `windowState`, and how do you know it is empty in `onTimer`?

Comment: thanks,David, I add some logs in processElement and onTimer, so I can know some value had been stored into windowState.